# Fastest way to convert vector of chars to a string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, std

I have a vector of chars (actually unsigned chars):

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vec;
```

I would like to cast it/ copy it to a string object. I have tried to do this in the following way:

```
std::string requestedName;

for (auto letter : vec)
{
    requestedName.append((char)letter);
}
```

But compiller says that such conversion is not possible. I would aprichiate all help.

Comment: Having the same answer does not make a question a duplicate. This question is specifically about efficiency.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the operator `+=` to perform this concatenation

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vec {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
std::string requestedName;
for (auto letter : vec)
    requestedName += letter;
```

[Working demo](http://cpp.sh/2xa7)

Also instead of concatenating in a loop, you can use the following overload of the `std::string` constructor

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vec {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
std::string requestedName{ vec.begin(), vec.end() };
```

Comment: I can't see any reason to use the unnecessarily inefficient concatenation approach.

Comment: @juanchopanza Neither can I, which is why I recommended using the constructor. I was just noting that `operator+=` would fix how they were trying to `append` to the string.

Comment: If the `std::vector<unsigned char> vec` initilized with interger like `std::vector<unsigned char> vec {0, 1, 2, 3};`, the output is blank, any good idea to solve this ?